# AngularJS - ngRepeat and ngModel

Tags: angularjs

I have spent the better part of a few hours writing and re-writing this, and am probably just going to write my own directive here if there isn't an answer.

I have a columnized display of inputs, 10 in each of the 6 columns.  I am using 2 ngRepeat directives to display them.  I am placing 6 fiddles below with my varied attempts at getting them to work right.  The problem is, when I use an array of objects, all the data are updated simultaneously.  View Fiddle #1 below to see the example.

Here is a quick snippet of the code, which you can also see on the fiddle page.  If anyone has some pointers or a way to get #1, #2, or #6 to work, please let me know!

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='EntryCtrl'>
<div class="span2" ng-repeat="a in [0,1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div ng-repeat="i in entry.slice($index*10, ($index*10)+10)" ng-class="{'control-group': true, error: !entry[($parent.$index*10)+$index].correct}">{{($parent.$index*10)+$index}}<input type="text" class="span12" id="entry-{{($parent.$index*10)+$index}}" ng-model="entry[($parent.$index*10)+$index].input" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('EntryCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.entry=filledArray(60,{input:'',correct:true});
}]);
function filledArray(len, val) {
    var rv = new Array(len);
    while (--len >= 0) {
        rv[len] = val;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Fiddle #1:  Array of objects using ng-model pointing to `entry` using `$index` and `$parent.$index`: http://jsfiddle.net/DFEkG/ -- **All models update simultaneously**

Fiddle #2: Array of objects using ng-model pointing to `i` instead of `$index`: http://jsfiddle.net/DFEkG/1/ -- **All models update simultaneously**

Fiddle #3: Array using ng-model pointing to `entry` using `$index` and `$parent.$index`: http://jsfiddle.net/DFEkG/2/ -- **Weird behavior**

Fiddle #4 Array using ng-model pointed to `i` instead of `$index`: http://jsfiddle.net/DFEkG/3/ -- **Broken**

Fiddle #5 Array using only `$index` and `$parent.$index` and array only in ng-repeat directive: http://jsfiddle.net/DFEkG/4/ -- **WORKS! But not as object**

Fiddle #6 Same as technique as 5, but with an object: http://jsfiddle.net/DFEkG/5/ -- **Same as fiddles 1 and 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `filledArray` function. It assigns the same exact object to each array item. The same object `{input: '', correct: true}` is referenced in all 60 instances.

So, to fix it you can simply make a new copy of it on each iteration:

```
function filledArray(len, val) {
    var rv = new Array(len);
    while (--len >= 0) {
        rv[len] = angular.copy(val);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjBvW/).

Comment: Genius. I never would have thought that was the issue.